# Point forces doing work

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, work

So I have a question:

> In a children's park, there is a slide which has a total length of 10 m and a height of 8m. Vertical ladder is provided to reach the top. A boy weighing 200 N climbs up the ladder to the top of the slide and slides down to the ground. The average friction offered by the slide is three tenth of his weight.
>
> Find the work done by the ladder on the boy as he goes up. Neglect any work done by forces inside the body of the boy.

My question is: how does the ladder do any work on the boy?
So the boy pushes on the ladder with his feet at a point and the ladder pushes back at his feet at that point.

But don't point forces do no work (in the words of my teacher) or something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are correct. In the rest frame of the ladder, the point of contact between the ladder and the boy's foot never moves, so the ladder does no work. It is precisely the work done by forces inside the body of the boy that would be doing the work here. The fact that the problem says to ignore these forces might indicate they indeed want you to say the answer is $0\,\rm J$

However, physics problems like these can be written sloppily; even ignoring the issue raised by the OP, if the author of the problem is assuming the ladder does a non-zero amount of work, then they have not provided enough information, as you do not know the velocity of the boy at the bottom and at the top of the ladder. In this case, it is likely that whoever made this problem was assuming the boy starts and stops at rest when going up the ladder, and was really asking how much work is needed in order to get the boy to the top of the ladder; then the simple answer is just $mgh=1600\, \rm J$, of course.

In this particular case I would recommend just asking your teacher to clarify.

Comment: Indeed, the correct answer is 0, but it is wise to check with the instructor in case an incorrect answer is desired.

Comment: @Dale Yes thank you; that is why I included my final sentence :)

Comment: @BioPhysicist Thank you! This is a question from Concepts of Physics by HC Verma and the answer given is indeed 1600J.

Comment: So just to clarify, a force, internal or external, can only do work on an object if the point of application moves, right?

Comment: But what would the point of application be for an internal force (like the boy on himself)?

Comment: @Silverstreak it is not the **point** of application that is important. After all, you can say in a weird way that the point of application of the force from the ladder moves up the ladder. The important thing is the motion of the **material** at the point of application of the force. In this case, that is 0 for the force from the ladder. Inside the boy there are lots of very complicated forces, muscles pulling on bones, bones pushing on other bones, actin fibers moving on myosin fibers, etc.

Comment: This answer makes some important and useful observations, but I think it ultimately communicates the wrong point and does a disservice to the student. I've added an answer that I think details the perspective of the problem.

Comment: @jawheele I think calling it a disservice is kind of strong.

Answer (score 2):

Since the question asks about the work done by the ladder on the boy one needs only to considered the contact force on the boy due to the ladder and the displacement of that force along its line of action.
At the level I gauge the question to be there is no displacement of the force, thus the ladder does no work on the boy.
Why no displacement?
It is because the presumed assumption is that the mass of the ladder and Earth is very much greater than the mass of the boy, ie they are essentially, immovable.

> But don't point forces do no work (in the words of my teacher) or
> something?

I have not heard of this and do not believe it to be true.

---

If the system under consideration is the boy and the boy starts and finishes with the same kinetic energy then the net work done on the boy is zero.

This is where one has to deal with a very complex system - the human body.
A way forward is to consider the boy as an inert "body" and a massless "leg" which can do work at the expense of using up chemical energy.
The "leg" exerts two forces, a downward force on the ladder and an equal upward force on the "body".
The downward force does no work as that force does not move as it is contact with the ladder
.
The upward force does work as the displacement of the "body" is in an upward direction.
How much work does the upward force due to the "leg" do? $mg\times \Delta h$ and this is the work done by the boy in climbing the ladder.

Of course there are no distinct "leg" and "body", they are all part of the boy and the forces which I have mentioned are internal force developed within the boy by his muscles.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to offer an alternative perspective from the other two answers that renders the question meaningful, with the correct answer being $W = mgh \approx 1600$ J (as others have anticipated the problem likely intends). It's a bit of a read, but I worry some critical confusions may be taken away from the other answers that merit clarifying. What I'd like to draw attention to, in particular, is that the question asks for the work done by the ladder **on the boy**.

At the basis of classical physics is the (technically incorrect but widely useful) picture that matter is comprised of point particles following definite trajectories through space, and forces influencing these trajectories arise as pairwise interactions between particles. We define the work done by such a force on a given particle to be $W = \int \vec F \cdot d \vec{x}$ over the particle's path. One might now look at our problem and say that the actual particles subject to the ladder's force don't seem to be moving as the force is applied, so the relevant "$d \vec x$" is $0$ and no work is done by the ladder on these particles.

A cursory understanding of the behavior of particles, however, negates this: individual constituent particles of matter, in the boy's shoe or anywhere else, are in constant and erratic thermal motion. We cannot possibly know their exact trajectories, so computing the work done on an individual particle is hopeless in practice (not to mention quantum complications to the entire picture at this scale). Clearly there's something to our observation leading us to zero work, though, so what did we really mean?

What we must keep in mind is that, in real macroscopic situations, we **never** undergo analysis at the level of individual particles. Instead, we invoke the vectorial properties of classical forces to discuss forces between *systems*, generally being large collections ($\sim$ Avogadro's number) of particles. We can then discuss the force $\vec F_{AB}$ imparted on system B by system A by (in principle) taking the vector sum of all pairwise forces on particles in B by particles in A. Indeed, we've already implicitly done this halfway by invoking the force imparted by "the ladder" above. Now, we define the work done **on system B by system A** to be $W_{AB} = \int \vec F_{AB} \cdot d \vec{x} $, taken not over any individual particle's trajectory, but the average trajectory of system B, namely the trajectory of B's **center of mass**. It is with these choices that Newton's laws and the Work-KE theorem carry over from particles to systems. Moreover, with this definition, we must now accept that **there is no universal notion of "The work done by the ladder (system A)"-- it depends on which system we choose as B**.

We can now see that what we really meant before in claiming that the ladder did no work is that the work done by the ladder system on a system comprised of, say, the boy's shoe (or a small clump thereof) is zero. The center of mass of such a system averages out the thermal motions of individual particles and is legitimately at rest, so our prior argument goes through.

That's great, except this is obviously not the system B that the question asks us about. The question asks us about the work done by the ladder (system A) on the boy (system B), and the boy's center of mass does, in fact, move as the ladder's force is applied, so our prior argument that the work was zero does not hold. What's more, since the only external forces on the boy in his climb are the ladder's force and gravity, and since the boy presumably begins and ends his climb at rest, the work done by the ladder balances that done by gravity (by the Work-KE theorem), i.e. $W_{AB} = mgh$.

---

Aside: this does **not** contradict the fact that the energy imparted through this work was ultimately sourced from chemical reactions in the boy's body, as noted in BioPhysicist's answer. All the forces within the boy's body are internal to his system, so they cannot accelerate his center of mass directly-- the ladder is simply an intermediary that allows the chemical energy to accelerate the boy's center of mass. An analogous scenario would be suddenly releasing a compressed spring in space-- its center of mass does not move as it decompresses and oscillates. If you place the spring against a massive wall before releasing it, however, the wall provides an intermediary to impart the spring's stored energy into COM motion.

Comment: The issue I have with this interpretation is that we usually understand work to involve a transfer of energy. In this case the ladder is not transferring any energy to the boy, and so it is odd to redefine work just so that we can let the problem make sense and say the ladder does work on the boy. This is why I usually never talk about systems doing work, but rather be careful to specify that forces do work.

Comment: @BioPhysicist It's not a redefinition: it's **the** definition of work between the ladder and the boy, chosen so as to be compatible with our notion of energy (through the work-KE theorem). One cannot escape collecting into systems to do classical physics in practice-- this is why I mentioned erratic thermal motion. The failure of classical physics is that it's inordinately unwieldy (if not entirely nonsense) when zoomed in, but its success is that its framework is entirely robust to zooming out until this is a nonissue. This definition is precisely that which ensures the framework is robust.

Comment: @BioPhysicist Energy here is being transferred from the chemical bonds in the boy's body to his COM motion, with the ladder an intermediary. Internal chemical reactions by themselves can only rearrange the boy's mass. As the ladder obstructs the rearrangement, the chemical energy is deposited into the ladder (imagine the surface minutely compressing like a trampoline), but Earth's inertia causes the energy to rebound back to the boy's COM motion. So energy is effectively transferred along: chemical --> ladder --> boy's COM motion. The above definition of work captures the second transfer here.

Comment: In the limit where the ladder becomes a rigid body we would expect no "trampoline" though. The motion of the boy up the ladder does not depend on the springiness of the ladder (in the "tiny trampoline regime" at least). Even then if you want to include that, the "trampoline" would do negative work and then positive work, resulting still in no work.

Comment: @BioPhysicist No material is perfectly rigid. But precisely! That the "trampoline" does no net work on the individual particles it rebounds means the ladder indeed contributes no energy of its own; it only redirects the local motion induced by chemical reactions so that COM motion is achieved. The point, though, is that energy is momentarily stored in the trampoline and then returned. The return is the transfer described by our definition of work on the boy. This is the sense in which the definition reflects an energy transfer, even though the energy all ultimately came from the boy.

Comment: If you are treating the ladder as a spring, then your energy "transfer" is really taking in energy and then putting it right back out, for a total transfer of no energy. When we talk about doing work, we talk about a net energy transfer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147921/discussion-between-jawheele-and-biophysicist).

Comment: @jawheele So basically there are two answers…..depending on how you look at the problem?

Comment: And a point force CAN do work depending on what we consider as the system it’s trying to do work on?

Comment: @Silverstreak Indeed. One can either take the fundamental perspective that work is the sum of works done on all individual particles, giving zero, or the scale-invariant perspective that work between systems is computed via COM motion and affects COM KE. Neither is wrong-- just different concepts with different advantages. The former is useful for tracking where the energy actually comes from; the latter for characterizing COM motion. I think intro courses often adopt the latter, but it's worth consulting your instructor. You might do well to show them these answers and ask their thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

This is intended to add one more perspective which is, I believe, consistent with the answers given by @BioPhysicist and @Farcher.

Clearly the energy that raises the boy up the ladder comes from the boy himself. Chemical potential energy of his cells is converted to mechanical energy doing work to elevate the boy (plus thermal energy, as the conversion of chemical potential energy to mechanical energy by humans is not 100 % efficient). The question is, what is the role of the ladder (in combination with the Earth)?

One way to look at the role of the ladder is that of "redirecting" the force exerted by the boy back on the boy due to Newton's 3rd law, causing the elevation of the boy. There is an effect on the ladder/Earth as well in order to satisfy conservation of momentum of the boy-ladder/Earth system. But because the mass of the Earth is so grea, the effect appears infinitesimal.

This situation is not unique to the ladder climbing example. Here are some other examples, to name a few:

1. An ice skater exerts a pushing force on the fixed rail of an ice skating rink. The rail exerts and equal and opposite force on the skater per Newton's 3rd law, accelerating the skater away from the rail and giving the skater kinetic energy. The energy comes from the skater. The role of the rail is to "redirect" the skater's force.
2. A person climbs a rope. The person exerts a pulling force down on the rope and the rope exerts an equal and opposite force up on the person per Newton's 3rd law. The equal and opposite forces are static friction. The force the rope applies up on the person elevates the person. The energy that elevates the person comes from the person. The role of the rope is to "redirect" the downward pulling force of the person upward.
3. Acceleration of a car (non biological example). The torque on the drive wheel of the car exerts a static friction force back on the ground. The ground exerts and equal and opposite static friction force forward on the wheel per Newton's 3rd law, enabling the car to accelerate. The energy that accelerates the car comes from the chemical potential energy of the fuel. The role of the ground is to "redirect" the backwards static friction force on the ground forward on the car.

Hope this helps.